# Using vuetify.js to create a table and sub table -- not sure where to start

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

So we have a system of tasks and replies, and I need to present this in a web application.  Our dev team uses vuetify.js, but I haven't found any examples in our current repo if what I'm trying to do.

I basically need to build a table with the Task details like subject, date, assigned to, etc, then below each Task row show all the replies which will have a different set of headers.  I guess from a SQL standpoint it'd be the replies grouped by the parent task.  The closest thing I found was [Grouped Rows](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables#grouped-rows), but this seemed to group by just a single field.  I need two distinct headers between the main table and sub tables which I haven't found any examples of.

An example I guess would be this:

```
ID   Subject                    Assigned To            Date       Status
123  Need to do something       John B                 2020-02-01 Active
         Mike R  User request was submitted            2020-02-01 
         John B  Called User                           2020-02-01
         Mary Q  User called back with details         2020-02-02
         John B  Waiting on pc support to fix          2020-02-03
223  Need to do something else  Jason Q                2020-02-04 Closed
         Tom E   User Email - Password Reset           2020-02-04
         Jason Q Called user and reset password        2020-02-04
```

Admittedly I'm new to Javascript and using vue or vuetify.js, but if I can find an example of this that'll be enough to get me running.

Thanks for the advise on this project.

Comment: you can use the extended slot to put your second table

Answer (score 2):

You could do something along these lines, using [Expandable rows](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables#expandable-rows) and [scoped slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Scoped-Slots):

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
 
Vue.component('my-component', {
  template: '#my-component',
  data() {
    return {
      headers: [
        { text: 'ID', value: 'id' },
        { text: 'Subject', value: 'subject' },
        { text: 'Assigned To', value: 'assignedTo' },
        { text: 'Date', value: 'date' },
        { text: 'Status', value: 'status' }
      ],
      replyHeaders: [
        { text: 'Title', value: 'title' },
        { text: 'Date', value: 'date' }
      ],
      tasks: [
        {
          id : 123,
          subject: 'Need to do something',
          assignedTo: 'John B',
          date: '2020-02-01',
          status: 'Active',
          replies: [
            { id: 1, title: 'User request was submitted', date: '2020-02-01'},
            { id: 2, title: 'Called User', date: '2020-02-01'},
            { id: 3, title: 'User called back with details', date: '2020-02-02'},
            { id: 4, title: 'Waiting on pc support to fix', date: '2020-02-03'}
          ]
        },
        {
          id : 223,
          subject: 'Need to do something else',
          assignedTo: 'Jason Q',
          date: '2020-02-04',
          status: 'Closed',
          replies: [
            { id: 5, title: 'User Email - Password Reset', date: '2020-02-04'},
            { id: 6, title: 'Called user and reset password', date: '2020-02-04'}
          ]
        }
      ],
    };
  }
});

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify()
});
```

```css
.sub-table.theme--light.v-data-table { background: transparent; }
.sub-table .v-data-table-header { display: none; }
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet"><link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet"><link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.21/vue.min.js"></script>    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script><style>.as-console-wrapper{display: none!important}</style>
 
 <div id="app">
   <v-app>
     <my-component></my-component>
   </v-app>
 </div>
 
 <template id="my-component">
   <v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="tasks"
    item-key="id"
    class="elevation-1"
    show-expand
  >
    <template v-slot:expanded-item="{ headers, item }">
      <td :colspan="headers.length">
        <v-data-table
          class="sub-table"
          :headers="replyHeaders"
          :items="item.replies"
          item-key="id"
          class="elevation-0"
          hide-default-footer
        ></v-data-table>
      </td>
    </template>
  </v-data-table>
 </template>
```